# SP2016 - Site check-in log

Tags: 2016, check-out, check-in, audit-log-reports

Our site has multiple administrators. I need to be able to track when/whom checks the site/pages in/out. Where would I find this data?

Answer (score 0):

All the admins login into the the site with same account(Farm Account)? If they have different accounts, you want which pages they have accessed it?

We have multiple admins who uses same Farm account to login, hence we started taking RDP(Remote desktop protocol) reports. This was done developing a powershell script, when someone take a RDP of any server in FARM, it sends an email with their machine IP and Account name.

If you want which sites\pages they have accessed, you can get that information from IIS logs. Weblogic expert tool(Free version available) analyze the IIS logs and gives a report of that information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. No, there is no farm account - each with distinct AD login. When a page is checked in, sometimes, the person who did it "forgets" that they were the last owner of the change and I need to be able to track that with certainty.

Comment: You can check page last modified! to have a detailed operations performed, uls logs and IIS logs which help you for sure.